# Async task within MvvmCross Command not returning

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, async-await, mvvmcross

I am building a small project using MvvMCross within a Xamarin PCL project and having issue with an async Task that I am calling within a command that is bound to a button.

I have a fake web service where-in I simply call Task.Delay(3000). When the process gets to this point it simply sits and does nothing.

I originally had the command call using the .wait() call but read somewhere that this was a blocking call and cant be miced with "async / wait"

Could someone help and possible give me a hint as to where I am going wrong on the command binding please ?

https://bitbucket.org/johncogan/exevaxamarinapp is the public git repo, the specific command is

```
public ICommand SaveProfile
```

within the ProfileViewModel.cs file.

The specific code is:

```
public ICommand SaveProfile
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() =>
            {
                if (_profile.IsValidData())
                {
                    // Wait for task to compelte, do UI updates here
                    // TODO Throbber / Spinner
                    EnumWebServiceResult taskResult;
                    Mvx.Resolve<IProfileWebService>().SendProfileToServer(_profile).Wait();

                    if(_profileWebService.getLastResponseResult() == true){
                        taskResult = EnumWebServiceResult.SUCCESS;
                    }else{
                        taskResult = EnumWebServiceResult.FAILED_UNKNOWN;
                    }
                    //_profileWebService.SendProfileToServer(_profile).Wait();
                    // Close(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The web service class () is:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ExevaXamarinApp.Models;

namespace ExevaXamarinApp.Services
{
public class FakeProfileWebService : IProfileWebService
{
    public int _delayPeriod { get; private set; }
    public bool? lastResult;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:ExevaXamarinApp.Enumerations.FakeProfileWebService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// 3 second delay to simulate a remote request
    public FakeProfileWebService()
    {
        _delayPeriod = 3000;
        lastResult = null;
    }

    private Task Sleep()
    {
        return Task.Delay(3000);
    }

    public bool? getLastResponseResult(){
        return lastResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the profile to server asynchronously
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>EnumWebServiceResultFlag value</returns>
    /// <param name="profileObject">Profile model object</param>
    public async Task SendProfileToServer(Profile profileObject)
    {
        // Validate arguments before attempting to use web serivce
        if (profileObject.IsValidData())
        {
            // TODO: Return ENUM FLAG that represents the state of the result
            await Sleep();
            lastResult = true;
        }else{
            lastResult = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Mvx.Resolve<IProfileWebService>().SendProfileToServer(_profile).Wait();
`

Comment: Yea thats where I call the async function but once inside "SendProfileToServer" and reaches the Sleep() function it sits doing nothing. Removing the .wait() call doesnt help either. Is there a way to make the "public ICommand SaveProfile" get call/property async ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
    public ICommand SaveProfile
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(async () =>              // async added
            {
                if (_profile.IsValidData())
                {
                    // Wait for task to compelte, do UI updates here
                    // TODO Throbber / Spinner
                    EnumWebServiceResult taskResult;
                    await Mvx.Resolve<IProfileWebService>().SendProfileToServer(_profile).ConfigureAwait(false);         // await, confi.. added

                    if(_profileWebService.getLastResponseResult() == true){
                        taskResult = EnumWebServiceResult.SUCCESS;
                    }else{
                        taskResult = EnumWebServiceResult.FAILED_UNKNOWN;
                    }
                    //_profileWebService.SendProfileToServer(_profile).Wait();
                    // Close(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

---

```
    private async Task Sleep()                                 // async added
    {
        return await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);   // await, confi... added
    }

    public async Task SendProfileToServer(Profile profileObject)
    {
        // Validate arguments before attempting to use web serivce
        if (profileObject.IsValidData())
        {
            // TODO: Return ENUM FLAG that represents the state of the result
            await Sleep().ConfigureAwait(false);                      // await, confi... added
            lastResult = true;
        }else{
            lastResult = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that the context from the UI and the async cause a deadlock.

Comment: Wow Sean, superb, thank you! This has been bugging me the last 3 hours. Just had to also remove the 'return' in the Task Sleep()  but your solution otherwise 100%.

Comment: @JohnCogan, note though that `MvxCommand` constructor takes `Action` rather than `Func<Task>`, so you're supplying an `async void` lambda, what potentially has a bunch issues. For more appropriate solution, check [Stephen Cleary's 
Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx).

Comment: @JohnCogan: There's a full explanation of this kind of deadlock [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: It would probably be a good choice to use `MvxAsyncCommand` here instead of `MvxCommand`.